# Wordpress Stub query_vars

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to create a stub for get_query_vars during unit test?

I have tried mocking the WP_Query objects and added parameters to it, but when get_query_vars, gets the vars, it gets from the current post/page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Apparently one way to make the stub is to move the get_query_vars into a method an stub it using a mock of the method.
2. The other way is to test indirectly by calling another method that invokes the get_query_var.
3. Jump the get_query_var method, using the following methods as public.